# How can I fill a numpy array with numpy arrays with different shapes?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to fill a numpy array with multiple numpy arrays of different shapes. For example, I have numpy arrays with shapes (4, 1000) and (4, 2000), and I want to combine them into a single numpy array.

Currently, my data is stored in a list like this: [numpy array, numpy array, ..., numpy array]. I want to transform it into a numpy array structure like this: numpy array(numpy array, numpy array, ..., numpy array).

I have already come across some guidelines suggesting the use of dtype=object, but I'm still encountering an error: "ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4, 1597) into shape (4,)".

Am I missing something in my approach? Is there another way to solve this task effectively?

Comment: what's wrong with the list?

Comment: make a object dtype array of the desired size, and assign the  elements individually.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide an example of what you code, but this works for me.

```py
import numpy as np

arrays = np.array([np.array([1]), np.array([2,3])], dtype=object)
print(arrays)  # [array([1]) array([2, 3])]
```

Its not clear to me what the advantages of a `np.array` are over a `list` in this case.

Comment: your example has (1,) and (2,) shapes.  Test (2,1) and (2,3) shapes.

Answer (score 0):

The creation of 'ragged' arrays has been tightened up over the past several numpy versions.

This used to work:

```
In [225]: np.array([np.array([1]), np.array([2,3])])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[225], line 1
----> 1 np.array([np.array([1]), np.array([2,3])])

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

Now (as of 1.24?) we have explicitly give the dtype:

```
In [226]: np.array([np.array([1]), np.array([2,3])], dtype=object)
Out[226]: array([array([1]), array([2, 3])], dtype=object)
```

Normally `np.array` makes a multidimensional numeric dtype array.  `object` dtype is a fall back option, storing references in the array, not numbers.  Such an array is almost list like.    Computations on it are performed (if at all) at list comprehension speeds, not the fast compiled speeds of numeric arrays.

2d arrays can also be packed this way - if the first dimensions differ:

```
In [228]: np.array([np.ones((3,3)), np.zeros((2,4))], dtype=object)
Out[228]: 
array([array([[1., 1., 1.],
              [1., 1., 1.],
              [1., 1., 1.]]), array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
                                     [0., 0., 0., 0.]])], dtype=object)
```

`dtype` doesn't help if the first dimensions match:

```
In [229]: np.array([np.ones((2,3)), np.zeros((2,4))], dtype=object)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[229], line 1
----> 1 np.array([np.ones((2,3)), np.zeros((2,4))], dtype=object)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,3) into shape (2,)
```

Instead you have to create a "blank" array, and fill it:

```
In [230]: arr = np.empty(2, object)    
In [231]: arr[:] = [np.ones((2,3)), np.zeros((2,4))]    
In [232]: arr
Out[232]: 
array([array([[1., 1., 1.],
              [1., 1., 1.]]), array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
                                     [0., 0., 0., 0.]])], dtype=object)
```

This create/fill is also needed it all dimensions match, and you don't want a proper n-d numeric array.  So it's a good idea regarless of the dimension mix.